# How can i increase internal storage space,on my LG tribute?

Tags: internal-storage

Is there anything i can buy to increase my phones internal storage? I.e. a larger sd or sim or an app for my LG tribute? Plz help always getting the annoying "low storage" i currently have a 4gig external sd...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Internal storage is called internal storage for a reason; it's on a flash chip on the motherboard and can't be replaced. You might however be able to move some of your apps to the SD card if your phone supports that. There are apps for that.